# gradle do not update dependency if files are not equal

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, dependencies, repository

currently I'm investigating a problem occurred with testRuntime dependency in gradle 2.1.
The problem that if I put some file to repository and added it as dependency to project it's downloaded, and works fine but if I'm changing this file, because found that it was not valid when I was uploading it at first time, it wouldn't be updated in project and I should delete it and download it again.
The same works if I put any file with the same name, it wouldn't be updated.

So is it possible to update local file if file was changed in my repository?

FYI: --refresh-dependencies doesn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't replace the dependency in the repo, without updating version number - that is exactly what the minor revision number is for. Moreover if this is in development and you expect frequent changes, use SNAPSHOT qualifier. SNAPSHOT forces gradle to fetch the latest binary with same version number.

Comment: @RaGe I'm trying to find way to update file comparing by file hash or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here two variants to declare a dependency as changing. Changing means that the artifact can change in the repository without the version number changing. If you have a version number ending in `-SNAPSHOT` it is automatically defined as changing, as this is the Maven default behaviour. Artifacts of changing dependencies are cached by Gradle for 24 hours by default, but this duration is configurable.

```
dependencies {
    testRuntime('org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5') {
        changing = true
    }
    testRuntime group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate', version: '3.0.5', changing: true
}
```

Using `--refresh-dependencies` does not work, as it only tells gradle to look again into the repositories, e. g. if a dependency was not found in the repo but is present now and Gradle still remembers that it was not found. It might work to re-get a dependency that is a changing module, but I'm not sure about this.

Once Gradle found an artifact for a dependency in a repo that is not defined as changing module, it will not look into the repo again for the dependency if it is not a changing module, as non-changing modules should not change without a version change. So you would have to delete the Gradle caches to make it re-fetch the artifact if it changed without being defined as changing.